# C# .NET Console Application getting keyboard input

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

I am trying to make a console application and it (don't ask me why) requires keyboard input (DownArrow and UpArrow). So far so good. The keyboard input needs to be in a While(true) loop and run forever, it is checked with an if statement. I tried using `Console.ReadKey() == ConsoleKey.UpArrow;` but that seems to pause the loop from running. Anyway I can run an `if(Keyboard.input == Key.UpArrow){}` statement without pausing the loop (basically skipping over it if it isn't the case)?

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
while (true){

if (Console.ReadKey() == ConsoleKey.UpArrow){ // this pauses the loop until input, which is not what I want / need.
 // Do stuff
}
Frame.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you first need to check if there is a `KeyAvailable` in the cache, and *then* use `ReadKey()` to read it. After that, your code should work as you expect. The line of code that does this would look something like:

```
// Check if there's a key available. If not, just continue to wait.
if (Console.KeyAvailable) { var key = Console.ReadKey(); }
```

Here's a sample to demonstrate:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.WindowWidth / 2, Console.WindowHeight / 2);
    Console.CursorVisible = false;
    Console.Write('*');

    var random = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            switch (key.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (Console.CursorTop > 0)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, 
                            Console.CursorTop - 1);
                        Console.Write('*');
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    if (Console.CursorTop < Console.BufferHeight)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, 
                            Console.CursorTop + 1);
                        Console.Write('*');
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (Console.CursorLeft > 1)
                    {
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 2, 
                            Console.CursorTop);
                        Console.Write('*');
                    }
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if (Console.CursorLeft < Console.WindowWidth - 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write('*');
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        // This method should be called on every iteration, 
        // and the iterations should not wait for a key to be pressed
        // Instead of Frame.Update(), change the foreground color every three seconds  
        if (DateTime.Now.Second % 3 == 0) 
            Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor) random.Next(0, 16);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadKey` locks thread. You should create another thread and read key there.
Example Here:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pressed");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I tried it out, it doesn't run smooth tho. Anyway I can smooth it out?